# Load an existing field in a custom module

Tags: programmatically-created, drupal-8

In drupal 8 (or 7?), is it possible to load programmatically an existing field ?
I mean : 
from the drupal administration, I create a new custom content type with some fields. This fields have an unique machine name. I want create a form from a custom module. In this form, I want "load" the existing fields created in the custom content.

So, is it possible to load existing fields in a .php module ?

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to build a custom form with field values of a created node, you can load the node programmatically with `Node::load($nid)` and put the the values in the render array. This way you need a predefined node you created yourself, because you call it using it's ID.